# How to unmount NTFS USB stick in Mate?

Tags: usb-drive, ntfs

I am using the Mate desktop in Debian 9 Stable. I insert a USB stick and then it mounts automatically and opens in the file browser Caja.

I know I can unmount it by terminal, using 'umount /media/myuser/nameoftheusb' but I would like to have things easy for once and use the mouse and the graphical interface, which I believe is not asking much (it's just an USB drive, it has been around for more than a decade, I believe, and used by millions around the world, it's not any new fancy device).

Then I click with the secondary button and the only option is "eject" after which there will be an error message "unable to find block device for drive" and the USB will get useless until I format it again.

Is there any way to delve into the configuration files of Mate and activate an "unmount" option that actually works for unmounting NTFS USB sticks?

Comment: The relevant information your post is missing is how you *mount* the drive...

Comment: There is a panel applet in Mate, which can be added by right-clicking the panel, choosing Add To Panel and searching for Disk Mounter. It allows you to unmount or eject (a huge advantage over emasculated KDE).

Comment: @ajeh read the question history; that was edited in after my comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) will allow you to unmount a volume without ejecting the drive. Simply select the drive on the left and the partition on the right, and click the unmount/stop button below it.

Comment: Thanks but, what do you mean by "Disks"? Is it the name of a program? Hard drives do not give any trouble. It's specifically usb sticks that have been formatted in ntfs.

Comment: Link added to the answer.